# Build bcrypt from source, step by step using make

Tags: c++, cryptography, bcrypt

I know that this topic has been mentioned before, but I am quite desperate since any post related to my problem doesn't help me at all.

I want to use bcrypt in my C++ QT project.

Things i have done so far:

- I have downloaded bcrypt source code package "bcrypt-1.1.tar.gz" from this site: http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/
- I unpacked it into C:\bcrypt-1.1
- Directory contains makefile, which (as mentioned in bcrypt instruction) I should "make" so library is built.
- I have installed make using "Complete package, except source Setup" from this site http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm into following directory C:\make\GnuWin32.

And that's the point where im stuck.

How do i "run" this makefile with make? When I open cmd and type make inside  C:\bcrypt-1.1
 directory, i get "'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Problem might be trivial, but Im desperate for step-by-step solution.

Comment: You will need to install a windows version of GNU make.

Comment: Isn't it what i've mentioned in last point of thing i have down?